# Parsing Google GDEntry

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm using python to retrieve email forwarding settings from my domain via the Google Admin SDK. Specifically I'm using the following:

```
client = gdata.apps.emailsettings.client.EmailSettingsClient(domain='example.com')

client.ClientLogin(email='adminUsername@yourdomain', password='adminPassword', source='your-apps')
r = client.RetrieveForwarding(username='venu')
```

where r is a GDEntry(atom.data.Entry, LinkFinder) object. See https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#retrieving_forwarding_settings. However, I don't see a clean example of parsing/finding key:value pairs in the object. I would like to get the data from:

I thought something like r.GetAttributes(tag="forwardTo") would work, but no.

Answer (score 0):

The GData python client results would be retrieved like this:

forwarding_action = r.action

forwarding_enable = r.enable

forwarding_address = r.forward_to